# Java Thread Signalling does not return execution to loop

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a class that is instantiated in a Tread and started. The code goes like this:

```
private class StartCycle implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        ...
        while(pomodoroLeft > 0) {
            ...
            synchronized(runnable){
                try{
                  runnable.wait();
                } catch(InterruptedException e){}
            }
            runTime = shortLength * ONE_MINUTE; //These statements are not getting 
            runnable = new Clock();             //executed
            runnable.run();


        }
    }


}
```

The clock class with instance name runnable is as follows:

```
private class Clock implements Runnable
{

   public void run() {
                ...
                synchronized (this) {
                    runnable.notifyAll();
                }
                //here goes the alarm.
            }


    }
}
```

For some reason the execution of the first thread does not return to its path and statements after. Did I mess up notification? Or is there some other reason for that?

Comment: Looks like the code after the wait is supposed to notify. That is impossible.., when I'm asleep(wait) I can't wake up(notify) myself? When making `runnable = new Clock();`, does all code wait and notify the same instance? Do you use proper synchronisation to share the instance?

Answer (score 0):

If you're building an alarm/timer, just use the android built in AlarmManager

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, (1000 * 60), (1000 * 60), yourPendingIntent);
```

most likely if you build your own, your app will consume most of the cpu, which will lead to lowbat your user's device

[Alarm Manager API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)